# Client Communication Management Software (Letter generation and management)

Tags: communication

I'm looking for recommendations in the client communication area. Essentaly its document generation, dis

- Generate communications in multiple formats e.g. PDF, Html, email,
  post with data sourced from a custom source.  Data could be pushed
  via an API or Sourced from a data store.
- Source contents from other sources and include them in the generated communication e.g. Attached forms.
- Provides functionality for management of the definition of the
  templates and some sought of workflow that could include approval and pushing letters between different states
- Communications orchestration e.g. if its a letter allow it to be put in a folder or directly send an email and then send it to a document repository. Or for SMS distribute through a custom provider.
- Functionality that allows users to edit sections of the letter they have generated and then trigger the orchestration for distribution.

I'm aware of one or two products in this space such as opentexts xStream but im looking for something that is a little more open possible open source.